# CustomNavigationLayout for Appcompat theme through styles

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I have read the post to set the customNavigationLayout for Holo theme. Is there any similar thing for appcompat(Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar)?

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set it in the android manifest

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.Activity1"
      android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
/>
```